# How to extend jQuery plugin's methods?

Tags: jquery, plugins

In the following code i tried to extend my test plugin. I want to add a new method definition to existing plugin.

```
(function($) {
    var settings = {
        bg: 'white'
    };

    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            options = $.extend({}, options, settings);
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).data("test", options);
            });
        },
        whiten: function() {
            var options = this.data("test");
            this.css('background-color', options.bg);
        }
    };

    $.fn.test = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist');
        } 
    }  

})(jQuery);

// New Method Definition
 var methods = {     
        newMethod: function(){
            alert('umut');   
      }
 };


// Extending test plugin with newMethod
$.fn.extend(true,$.fn.test, methods );

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul').test().css('background-color', 'wheat');
    $('#go').click(function() {
        $('ul').test("whiten");
        // Calling newMethod
        $('ul').test("newMethod");    
    });
});
```

But i got following error at firebug console:

> uncaught exception: Method newMethod does not exist

How can i extend

```
var methods = {
}
```

block inside my test plugin?

Here is the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/NSVVv/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I'm changing my answer. This may be the simpler solution, since it requires less code change.  Add `methods` as a property of your plugin.  Add this line after you define your plugin function:

```
$.fn.test.methods = methods;
```

This needs to be inside your closure that defines the plugin.  The rest of your code should just work, extending `test` via `$.extend()` as you are already doing.

Here's my original answer:

If you want to be able to extend your plugin in this way, your plugin must expose a way to do so.  You could add `methods` as a property in `settings` and then deeply extend `settings.methods` with `options.methods` in your `init` method.

If you intend for `settings` to be the defaults, and `options` to override settings, you've got your arguments reversed in your call to `.extend()`.  Reverse your arguments, then add `true` as the first parameter to make it a deep extend:

```
options = $.extend(true, {}, settings, options);
```

Then put your methods in `settings`:

```
var settings = {
    bg: "white",
    methods: {
        init: function(options) {
            options = $.extend(true, {}, settings, options);
            ... // etc.
         },
         ...
    }
};
```

Then, instead of extending your plugin's methods via `$.extend()`, do it in your `init` call:

```
$(".foo").test("init", { methods: methods });
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest way of modify its source without touching too many lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For those who use the plugin structure recommended by jQuery team, it will be hard to add methods given that there is only one function added to the $.fn object and thus, only one public function. So, in my case, I decided that the best solution was to add a method to the plugin that extends the methods variable. This will be accessible from outside the plugin as any other function. Example here:

```
(function($) {
    var settings = {
        bg: 'white'
    };

    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            options = $.extend({}, options, settings);
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).data("test", options);
            });
        },
        whiten: function() {
            var options = this.data("test");
            this.css('background-color', options.bg);
        },
        extendMethods: function(newMethods) {
            $.extend(true, methods, newMethods);
            return $(this);
        }
    };

    $.fn.test = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist');
        } 
    }  

})(jQuery);
```

Voila! Then you just need to call it like this:

```
$.fn.test('extendMethods',{...Methods object here...});
```

Note: I'm aware that this requires you to edit the plugin code in the first place, but there's not much to add and may be viable in many cases. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can't as `methods` is only local to the function. You can only extend it if you make it accessible from the outside.

Comment: This is the recomended style of writing a plugin which i read at [jQuery/plugin/authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). How can i modify this plugin to make it extendible for new methods ?

Comment: @Luffy: As I said, you would have to make `methods` accessible from the outside. One option would be to create another function which accepts an object and extends the methods.... the question why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to extend a plugin which is smilar to this without touching its source code. I dont want to modify its source everytime they released an upgrade.